# Want to build parent-child relationships between custom post types created with CPT UI

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I've gone through similar queries from the past but couldn't find a solution that works for me.

So I created 3 different custom post types with the CPT UI plugin. They are called 'careers', 'vacancies', 'our-staff', respectively.

What I want to achieve is set 'careers' as the parent, and both 'vacancies' and 'our-staff' as children of 'careers', so that the breadcrumb lists on the children pages dynamically show as follows:

Home > Careers > Vacancies

Home > Careers > Our Staff

In the CPT UI interface, hierarchical is set to 'true' for all 3 custom post types.

For the two intended children pages 'page-attributes' is ticked under 'supports'.

However the breadcrumb lists on the intended children pages still show as

Home > Vacancies

Home > Our Staff

i.e. skipping the parent page.

When I try getting the parent page ID of the children pages, it shows as "0" meaning the parent page is not set as intended.

I've tried using the Add-Hierarchy-Parent-to-Post plugin, but no luck....

Would be grateful for any tips, including workarounds to get the result I am hoping for.

Comment: Hello KMPudd - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Vanilla WordPress does not support hierarchical relationships between post types - only between individual posts of the same hierarchical post type. By the database's design, it is technically possible to have parent/child relationships between posts of different types, but I don't believe that the WordPress codebase inherently supports that situation. If this is some functionality which the CPT UI plugin adds you will need to pose your question in their official support channels or associated communities.

Comment: In the past, I've handled such situations by creating those custom relationships using a custom taxonomy or post meta-data, and changing the logic which generates the breadcrumb to factor them in... WordPress also does not inherently offer a breadcrumb implementation, so it may be necessary to consult your theme's support channels as well